# Visual Studio 2003 can't navigate to the definition of "IIdentity" or "StringTable"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Principal;

public class SystemPrincipal : IPrincipal {

    private IIdentity       _identity;
    private StringTable     _roles;

    public SystemPrincipal(IIdentity id, StringTable roles) {

        _identity = id;
        _roles = roles;;
    }

    public IIdentity Identity {

        get { return _identity; }
    }

    public bool IsInRole(String role) {

        bool result = false;

        if (null != _roles) {
            result = _roles.Contains(role);
        }
        return result;              
    }
}
```

I want to see the definition of IIdentity or StringTable so I right click and choose 
goto definition but I get "cannot naviate to" IIdentity or StiringTable.

Based on a google soultion I rebuilt the project but that did not solve the issue.

Comment: Where are these types defined? Same Project or reference?

Comment: Try restarting visual studio, and or your PC as well

Comment: That's strange. I'm able to F12 `IIdentity` no problem. VS2010 Ultimate

Comment: That is the question. They are not in same project for sure because if I do a search I cannot find them defined anywhere.

Comment: @tnw And what do you get as the definiton of IIdentity?

Also how about StringTable?

Comment: @SNash Just hit up the MSDN defintion. [IIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.aspx)

Comment: I'm guessing maybe because my project is a mixture of Vb.NET and C# files VS2003 gets confused, which in this case this is bug.

Comment: Do you have the correct DLL references in your project? If the code is from Visual Studio 2003/.NET 1.1, you might have to update some DLL references for it to compile.

Comment: are you able to compile this code? May be some references are missed.

Comment: @Cameron Tinker Obviously I do. Otherwise I would get compile error.

Comment: @Anton, Compile is successful.

Comment: So I do have a soultion with different projects. Those projects with files all VB.NET or All C# do not have this issue. This issue only shows on a project with a mixture of VB.NEt and C# files.

Comment: I have a hard time to understand why they made a project with mixutre of VB and C# files. All of these files are tiny so this could be made by one developer.

Comment: They don't let me use VS2005 or plus. Also I'm stucked with dinasaur old Framework 1.1.

Comment: Those classes are from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381050(v=vs.85).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.aspx